# How does tf.create_partitioned_variables work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to figure out how to use [tf.create_partitioned_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/create_partitioned_variables)
I am reading the documentation but I am having a hard time understanding.

Could anyone explain how it works and give some examples of its usage?

From what I understand I can use it to get a list of slices from a variable.
I just dont understand how I get the slices

ex:
how would i get a list of `[[1.],[3.]]` from `tf.Variable(np.array([[1.0],[3.0]]), dtype=tf.float32)`

or list of

```
[[[1 0] [3 0]], [[0 5] [0 7]]]
```

from

```
[[[1 0]
  [3 0]]

 [[0 5]
  [0 7]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 arguments are required. The first is the shape of the input tensor. The second is the split specification. The API currently supports splits along one dimension only. The split specification has the same number of dimensions as the shape, with one split being >= 1 and the others being 1. The last argument is the tensor itself, or a callable that returns it.

First example:

```
tf.create_partitioned_variables(v.shape, [2, 1], v)
```

Second example:

```
[tf.squeeze(v) 
    for v in tf.create_partitioned_variables(
        v.shape, [2, 1, 1], v)]
```